# TYPO3 Extbase - Check if property in model x is set before adding it to container of model y

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have two models `file` and `filecontainer`.

Let's assume I have a checkbox in `file` called `Allow to add`.

[image: File model]

And I should only be able to add the file to the container of `filecontainer`, if the property `Allow to add` is set in that file and if possible show an alert if someone tries to add it even though `Allow to add` is not set.

**Filecontainer**

[image]

Is this possible?

PS: I just ask this question for learning purposes to see what is possible and what not.

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Introduction/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the TCA type `select`. You can specify a `foreign_table_where` clause there to filter the records shown from the `file` table.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But I am not sure how to use it, the example on the following page starts with `AND` so do I have to use it like this:

`"foreign_table_where" => "AND [foreign_table].AllowToAdd=1",` ?

(https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#columns-select)

Comment: I had to correct it to `"foreign_table_where" => "AND tx_myextension_mytable.AllowToAdd=1",`